# OnNewItem event for TMainMenu

Tags: delphi, menuitem

I have a `TMainMenu` on a form and I want to add an event when an `TMenuItem` is added to the `TmainMenu`.

`TMainMenu.OnChange(Sender: TObject; Source: TMenuItem; Rebuild: Boolean)` doesn't seem to work because there is no difference in params values when adding or removing or updateing items. And I need to react only to new items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

Looking at the code for `TMenuItem.Add()` it's clearly obvious that the only event that's triggered is the `OnChange`. Because of that there's no easy and clean solution.

## Clean solution - refactor your code

My first thought: surely you *know* when a menu item is added to the menu, it's your code that's adding it. The best option would be to simply re-factor the code so it doesn't directly add the menu item but calls a method of your choice. For example, if you're using code like this:

```
someMenu.Add(M); // where someMenu is an existing menu item and "M" is the new item
```

you could refactor it to something like this:

```
// procedure definition in private section of main form, or somewhere else relevant:
procedure AddSubMenu(const Where, What: TMenuItem);

// Refactor your code to do this:
AddSubMenu(someMenu, M);

// Then in the "AddSubMenu" you can do whatever you want to do for new items:
procedure TFormName.AddSubmenu(const Where, What: TMenuItem);
begin
  // Do your thing.
  // Then do the actual adding of the menu item
  Where.Add(What);
end;
```

## Alternative solution - track existing menu items

Use the `OnChange` item that you know gets called, recursively walk the list of existing `TMenuItems` and do something with them so you know you've seen them before. For example set the `Tag` to 1 - you'll know items with `Tag = 0` are new. Or add all items into a Dictionary so you can easily test what items are new and what items are pre-existing.

Here's an example `OnChange` handler using the `Tag` property to track rather a menu item is New or Old. Make sure you handle the initial creating of the Menu properly; For example, I'd assign the `OnChange` at runtime, from the form's `OnCreate`, after the Menu has been initialized from the DFM and after setting the `Tag` for all the design-time menu items to `1`:

```
procedure TForm1.MainMenu1Change(Sender: TObject; Source: TMenuItem; Rebuild: Boolean);
var i: Integer;

  procedure VisitMenuItem(const M: TMenuItem);
  begin
    if M.Tag = 0 then
    begin
      // First time I see this TMenuItem!

      // DO my thing
      ShowMessage(M.Caption);

      // Mark the item so I don't "Do my thing" again
      M.Tag := 1;
    end;
  end;

  procedure RecursivelyVisitAllMenuItems(const Root: TMenuItem);
  var i:Integer;
  begin
    VisitMenuItem(Root);
    for i:=0 to Root.Count-1 do
      RecursivelyVisitAllMenuItems(Root.Items[i]);
  end;

begin
  for i:=0 to MainMenu1.Items.Count-1 do
    RecursivelyVisitAllMenuItems(MainMenu1.Items[i]);
end;
```

Comment: I've fiddled with these solutions before. I was hoping for a more elegant solution (e.g. responding to an Windows Message), but life's tough :). Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The "refactor" solution is very elegant, and quite possibly easy to implement.

Comment: In itself, yes, it is elegant and easy to implement. But in my code it adds a dependency that I want to avoid. Anyway, I've solved that specific case and the question had more of an theoretical value.

Comment: Again looking at the code, the windows-message solution seems unlikely: The `TMenuItem.RebuildHandle` is called for each added `TMenuItem`, and when that happens multiple Handles might be destroyed and re-created. Even if there's a message sent from Windows when a new MenuItem is created, you'd get multiple such messages, not just the one for the altered menu item.